# Hiker’s Cabin Mystery | Pt. V

Tags: logical-deduction

**Be sure to see the previous parts and solve Part II because that’s the only one *without an answer!***

After you’ve unlocked the mystery of the map, you go to

> Chad

<sub><sub>*(Solution to Part IV)*</sub></sub>

to try and find this mystery hiker.

---

Once you arrive at the airport, you realize that security is a lot tighter than it should be. It takes three hours before a single person is released from security! You ask a security agent what’s going on and she says,
“There’s been an attack! We are trying to figure out who did it, still, and we have a lineup of people who could have done it. We would appreciate your help if you could figure out who the attacker was!”

Since you already have to find the hiker, you won’t get out of this airport until you figure out whodunnit!

The attack occurred at 5:15 PM on May 13th. Here is the lineup:

[image: lineup]

If all of their alibis are true, then none of them committed the attack. Therefore, one of the detainees must be lying!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was the one...

> who said they were writing outside from 5:00 to 7:35 PM

Reason:

> The sun sets at 6:16 PM on May 13, 2019.  Maybe they have a flashlight?  Or they are lying.
>  [image]

Comment: @Ak19 I see that.  Why did you not write it as the answer?

Comment: I’ll let you get some upvotes before I accept! Do you want to take a try at Part II? Just look up ‘Hiker’s Cabin Mystery | Pt. II’ :)

Comment: Sunset locally on May 13th is almost 9PM.

Comment: @DarkMatter I have no empirical evidence other than what Google told me when I typed "sunset in chad on may 13, 2019"

Comment: @LeppyR64 Chad the country, not Chad the person.  My bad.